# Dropdown validation from a named range referencing another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've got two workbooks, "Test" and "Screen_Reference_Data_Sheet". I am trying to create a dropdown list in "Test" by using a named range with data from the "Screen_Reference_Data_Sheet" workbook.

Below is the code I'm using, and it is throwing error Run Time Error 1004 on the ".Add Type:..." line.

I am able to accomplish this when only using data from one workbook, but it's when I am pulling data from another workbook that I am getting this error.

```
Sub GetScreenNames()
Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
RefFilePath = Path & "\Screen_Reference_Data_Sheet.xls"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(RefFilePath)

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = objWorkbook.Sheets("Keywords_Action_Screen").Range("B2:B4")
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="screenslistdata", RefersTo:=rng1

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween,    Formula1:="=screenslistdata"
End With

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not use references to other workbooks for Data Validation criteria.

If you try to do this manually, the error/warning will appear:

[image]

The next best solution I think is to convert the range's value to a variant array, and use that array to assign the list formula:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween,
        Formula1:=Join(Application.Transpose(rng1.Value), ",")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. So what's the next best solution? Would it be to copy the cell range from the other workbook into my active workbook, and create the named range from that newly moved data?

Comment: Your question was "What am I doing wrong". I believe I have answered that question already, but I will entertain the follow-up question. But please consider marking this answer as accepted, since I have answered it.  You can assign a range's values to an array, and you can assign an array to the validation formula, so do that (see revision, above) :)